# Ambiguity of addition

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, notation, arithmetic, binary-operations

In the case of addition, we are taught from early to just put a $+$ between the addends, 'this is $2+2$ this means $4$' and hence we define the value of $2+2$, however, I've seen 'addition' defined as a function, and the notation as $+(a,b)$ for functional notation.

This creates an issue, if different functions have different domains, they define different functions, so if we see $+$ as a function, how do we know which function is defined if we are just given a formula like:

$y=x+c$

My previous understanding is that 'addition is addition', but clearly this is not the case if my operator represents a function, I'm aware that 'addition' is defined differently for vectors, numbers etc, but this 'function' way of viewing it means that $+$ could be different functions even if we are just using real numbers.

Is the definition of the $a+b$ notation equivalent to $+(a,b)$? in which case how do we get to the situation that we can say $3+2=5$ is it that for all functions $+$ of different domains, that are defined at $(3,2)$ will have the value of $5$ so say the value of $3+2=5$?

Comment: Welcome to the world of [Abstract Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_algebra).

Comment: But yes, often in informal settings (and even in many formal settings), we just assume the reader intuitively knows which definition of $+$ we are using, given the context. If you're curious as to what exactly the formal definition of $+$ is, it essentially revolves around [Peano Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms) for natural numbers, [Cauchy Sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_sequence) for real numbers, and [Group Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_theory) for much of what's in-between.

Comment: Mathematical notation without context is often ambiguous. "$(a,b)$" could be an ordered pair, an open interval, the greatest common divisor, an inner product, etc, etc, etc. It is an author's duty make clear which interpretation is intended in a given instance (although context alone may be enough), and it is a reader's responsibility to stay vigilant. Sometimes, disambiguation can done by tweaking the symbol; with "addition functions", one might use, say, "$\oplus$" or "$\boxplus$" or "$\dotplus$", but these can require fancy typesetting that may not be available to every author or reader.

Answer (score 2):

If you see something of the form $A + B,$ generally
the objects $A$ and $B$ will both be members of some domain $D$
and the addition function $+: D\times D\to D$ will already have been defined.

If the domain is a commonly-used domain such as pairs of natural numbers,
integers, rational numbers, real numbers, complex numbers, quaternions,
vectors or matrices of real or complex numbers, etc., in most contexts
(other than an introductory textbook to the subject)
it may be assumed that the reader is already familiar with the definition
of addition usually used on that domain.
Therefore the addition operator/function is often used without giving a definition.

The properties of the usual domains of $+$ are such that we are guaranteed
that the result will always be in the domain, hence the function is well-defined.

I don't know if anyone ever dares to redefine $+$ differently than the
usual definition when the domain of $+$ is one of the commonly-used ones.
So there isn't much chance for ambiguity.
The larger source of ambiguity is the varied uses of the names of the domains: for example, someone might say the sum of two complex numbers is a real number when what they really mean is that the result is a complex number with zero imaginary part.

Comment: can a complex number with a real part and no imaginary part, be expressed as an element of the reals in more informal contexts? I understand that very strictly elements of $C$ and $R$ are different, but more informally I see the real number $a$ written as $a+0i$.

Comment: That's exactly the kind of "ambiguity" I meant. Very strictly the numbers are different, but we tend to identify $a\in\mathbb R$ with $a+0i\in\mathbb C$, that is, we treat them as if they were exactly the same mathematical object. It's an ambiguity that doesn't really matter unless you're in the midst of defining $\mathbb C$ in terms of $\mathbb R.$

Comment: of course, thanks for the good answers

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is one of the conventions most people follow writing math. However, it is almost always clear from context what is meant.

This is not only the case for binary operators though, any function can be "reused" in different contexts, for example, as you pointed out how vector addition is simply addition done component-wise, take any function $f$ that is defined on a field $\mathbb{F} $ and you implicitly have a function defined on any $\mathbb{F} $-vector space by simply applying $f$ to all the components of a vector (or more generally, transform the linear combination of a vector with regards to a basis by applying $f$ to the coefficients)

Granted, I have only actually seen this done in Machine Learning literature, but the point still stands.

A more common abuse of notation that is more traditionally done in maths is the equivalent application of a function $f$ defined on a set $A$ to the set $A$.

Comment: If $+$ is not explicitly defined, can we think of it as either 'the value of any addition function on any set in your universe' or if say we have the reals, we can consider it as addition on the reals, and if we have vectors, addition on vectors? Is addition on vectors a different function than on the reals?

Comment: You generally shouldn't assume an implicitly defined function to be very generic. This kind of "sloppiness" only really works if it is crystal clear from the context what the function represents. And yes, usually the function is very often indicated by what kinds of elements it operates on, it is a bit similar to polymorphic functions in programming. And yes, addition on vectors is a different function than on the reals. We just reuse the symbol because the odds of mixing the functions up in practice are virtually zero.

Comment: If we are given $f(x)=....$ and the function's domain is not previously defined, we generally assume $R$ is the domain, can we use the same principle here? If $+$ is not defined than I can't really give $a+b$ a value (maybe they are out of the domain) until I know this, I can only kind of assume it's something, or say well, they all have the same value, which is $a+b$ and define it that way.

Comment: I don't think that is correct. The domain usually is defined in the broader context of the writing. And even if not, it would be stated what kind of function $f$ is which would make it clear. Like, it would be stated it is linear, for example, and then you would only assume that the involved operations are defined on a general vector space.

Comment: So if I was given something in let's say a mechanics problem and a formula with a $+$ sum in it, how would I know which $+$ function they are referring to?, all I know is that it is defined on either reals or vectors, and I know what it does, but not it's specific domain, that's my point, addition and others are just used and they don't give us any other information.

Comment: Sorry, but this is really out of the scope for the Q&A format of this site. I thought you were talking about mathematical texts, but for texts from other fields you should ask somewhere else or for things such as assignments, you should ask the responsible people, there is no general way to answer that kind of question.

Comment: I'm not explaining myself well, I think I will edit this question, it's more about ambiguity of meaning generally, I will edit/ask the quetion better.

Answer (score 1):

Addition is a function but it's not *any* function. Unless explicitly said otherwise, $+$ is the usual addition of numbers.

Comment: How about the fact that $+$ could be defined over the reals, complex or natural numbers, could they be considered 'addition'

Comment: The definition of $+$ on the complexes extends that of the reals, which extends that of the naturals. in other terms $+_{\mathbb N \times \mathbb N} = +_{\mathbb R \times \mathbb R} \mid_{\mathbb N \times \mathbb N}$ and so on (I use the usual "restriction" notation). So if you want to add two naturals, you get the same results if you use the $+$ of the naturals or the $+$ of the reals. That's why we use the same notation for all these functions even though their domains are not the same. This is what mathematicians call a *convenient abuse of notation*.

Comment: We almost never study one of the standard operators as a function for its own sake, so the ambiguity on the domain in not a problem. For the rare instances we would want that, we just specify the domain and codomain in the statement.

Comment: For instance : "Theorem: $- : \mathbb N \times \mathbb N \to \mathbb Z$ is surjective but not injective".

Comment: We could say, that we essentially define the value of $a+b$ to be the value any of these functions take?

Comment: If you want, and it's not ambiguous because all these functions coincide whenever their domains intersect.

Comment: I think in the mathematics you learn at school (addition is just 'adding up') this is precisely how its taught and as a result it feels very odd to me to talk about different functions.

Comment: The fact that you can define many functions by just changing the domain and codomain does not change the fact that addition is "just adding up". This is true of any function. You have $\log : (0,+\infty) \to \mathbb R$ but also $\log : (0,1) \to (-\infty,0)$, and if you know complex analysis you can extend it to $\log : \mathbb C \setminus \mathbb R_- \to \mathbb C$.

Comment: I guess so, it's just a surprising fact for me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set of integers and addition operation "+" is an Abelian group, indicated as (Z,+), operation + combines two integers to form a third integer, addition is associative, zero is the identity element of addition, all integers n have the inverse element of addition − n, The addition is commutative because for any two integers m and n, m plus n is equal to n plus m